Stemwall/Foundation Repair - What Product?
I need to patch some horizontal cracking in the stem wall/foundation of our kitchen.  I’m not sure which product is appropriate to use.

Hydraulic cement or Rustoleum concrete patch appear to be the easier but I’m not sure if ready-mix concrete is required or another product.
Any advice or thoughts would be appreciated.

By color and thickness that looks like stucco.
I would use Stucco patch. Remove the loose crumbs and apply the patch.
To get the sand type of finish, Apply the patch with a stiff 2 or 3 inch putty knife, give it 10 minutes to set a little and then wipe with a lightly wet brush.
Then, when it's dry, prime and seal then repaint.

Thanks, it may well be. The house is stucco, and it sits below the drip edge.  I figured it may be concrete as it's the crawl space behind it, but it looks like there's some old lathe there as well.

If there is lathe there it's stucco.

I see the PVC in the wall, if that has warm or hot water running through it, you may want to consider wrapping it with some expansion material. The reason that popped off could have been the pipe may have expanded due to the temperature and formed a crack in the wall allowing moisture in.
I would highly recommend Quikrete 60 lb. Sand/Topping Mix  blended mixture of portland cement, graded sand and other approved ingredients. This mix is ideal for repairing and topping damaged concrete surfaces that are less than 2 in. thick. It can be applied down to a 1/2 in. thickness and still maintain the strength needed for traffic areas. And it doesn't have big aggregate so it will still be manageable to get a nice taper on your edges.
A little tip, apply bonding agent to the wall as well as your mix. It's extremely important to have the wall saturated with bonding agent or at the very minimum make sure it's saturated with water.
using a hard trowel (rectangle one) apply The mix to the wall don't play with it too much trying to get it perfect.
Let it set up a bit it!
from the looks of the picture I would make a little slurry and using a hand brush, dip it in the slurry and sling it on the wall and let it harden up a bit as well
then using the brush, lightly brush in the same direction along the foundation a couple times and you should be good to go ready for paint.
Good luck!
